# obtaining groovy value from map given computed key for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Given the map:

```
def mymap = ["first":"aaa", "second":"bbb", "third":"ccc"]
```

I would like to get the value for a key where the key is a parameter of the Jenkins job that runs this Groovy script.

I have tried a number of methods similar to

```
sh "echo the value is ${mymap.${paramValue}}"
```

but this is throwing the error

> " unclassified method java.util.LinkedHashMap"

Comment: sh "echo the value is ${mymap[paramValue]}" should work. (Refer http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-get-value-from-map-or.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way to fix this was to separate out getting the value from the map and feeding that value into the next step.

```
def value = mymap."${paramValue}"
sh "echo the value is ${value}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get method:

```
sh "echo the value is ${mymap.get(paramValue)}"
```